# RabbitMQ and F# - How to 'read' MQ messages and split content into Variables or an Array?

Tags: arrays, f#, rabbitmq

I hope you are well. I am a F# and programming newbie and I need some guidance on an issue reading data into F# from a RabbitMQ message queue.

I have been able to write a F# script which subscribes to a message queue(s) and receives data in a similar format to the below.

```
Received onData;FeedQ1;7.488;7.48813;1427315602762;8.61;8.31
```

I now need to learn how to split the 'string' message received from the message queue into Variables or an Array which can then be stored and/or used within my F# script. As you can see, the message above actually contains 7 fields which are separated by **;** characters.

I have tried searching the web and RabbitMQs resources but everything I have found seems to just detail making the actual connection to RabbiTMQ from F# and it doesn't go any further in terms of information on processing message data received from the MQ queue....

Any help is very much appreciated, Thank you!

**Actual F# fsx script shown below:**

```
#r "RabbitMQ.Client.dll"

open System
open RabbitMQ.Client
open RabbitMQ.Client.Events
open System.Text

let factory = new ConnectionFactory(HostName = "localhost")
(
use connection = factory.CreateConnection()
use channel = connection.CreateModel()
use channel1 = connection.CreateModel()

channel.QueueDeclare("FeedQ1", false, false, false, null) |> ignore
channel1.QueueDeclare("FeedQ2", false, false, false, null) |> ignore

let consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel)
channel.BasicConsume("FeedQ1", true, consumer) |> ignore
channel.BasicConsume("FeedQ2", true, consumer) |> ignore


printfn " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C"

let rec loop () : unit =
    let ea = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

    let body = ea.Body
    let message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body)
    printfn " [x] Received %s" message

    loop ()

loop ()
)
```

Comment: use Split() method: `let splited = message.Split(';')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm new to programming so need a little more information if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tell me what processing you are going to do, it will be easier to help

```
let message = "Received onData;FeedQ1;7.488;7.48813;1427315602762;8.61;8.31"
let splited = message.Split(';')
splited |> printfn "Array: %A"
splited.[0] |> printfn "First element: %s"
splited.Length |> printfn "Array length: %d"
```

Out:

```
Array: [|"Received onData"; "FeedQ1"; "7.488"; "7.48813"; "1427315602762"; "8.61";
  "8.31"|]
First element: Received onData
Array length: 7
```

http://ideone.com/SEyYov

More informantion:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Thank you Foggy Finder, this really helped me - I have been able to get the message broken up into an array using your code example above. I now need to work out how to work with the variables in the array! Once again thank you!